# PHP Validation Function in a Registration Session

Tags: php, validation

I'm am attempting to create a registration system, I have a function which checks through both the password and the username for specific registration. The problem is, when I submit and get $_POST details back, the functions that I call on are supposed to fill up a variable called $errors, which is then added to the session. The  problem is, that all the errors which should be reacting are not.

This is my function:

```
<?php

global $errors;

function validation($username, $password) {

    global $errors;
    $min = 9;
    $max_u = 20;
    $max_p = 32;

    header('login.php');

    if(strlen($username) < $min) {
        $errors .= "{$username} is too short for a username, it must be at least 8 characters long.<br/>";
    }

    if(strlen($password) < $min) {
        $errors .= "Your password is too short, it must be at least 8 characters long.<br/>";
    }

    if(strlen($username) > $max_u) {
        $errors .= "{$username} is too long for a username, it must be less than 20 characters long.<br/>";
    }

    if(strlen($password) > $max_p) {
        $errors .= "Your password is too long, it must be less than 32 characters long";
    }

    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/ ',$password)) {
        $errors .= "You used innapropriate characters in your username or password.<br/>";
    }

    if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/ ',$username)) {
        $errors .= "You used innapropriate characters in your username or password.<br/>";
    }
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $_SESSION["errors"] = $errors;
}
?>
```

Then, on my PHP form, and main page, I call upon it using the following:

```
<?php

    $errors;

    $second_header = "Registration Menu";
    require_once('includes/header.php');

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

        echo ($_SESSION['errors']);
```

I need to figure out the positioning of that ^

```
        validation(($_POST['username']),($_POST['password']));

    }


?>

<body>
    <form type="submit" name="registration" method="post">

        <br/>Username<input type="text" name="username">

        <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">
        <br/>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">

        <br/><input type="submit" name="register" value="Create Account">
    </form>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

I can't figure out why this function isn't working.

Comment: Well, for one, you're never calling `session_start()` so anything you stuff into $_SESSION is going to be lost when the script(s) exit.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Do var_dump($errors); before you check if empty($errors). Let's see what you got there.

Comment: Off question, but in `"{$username}"` you can do without the `{}`, double quotes parse variables.

Comment: I do a session start as a require_once at the beginning of my php code. As well, the results I'm getting is just password being to short when I leave the fields blank. Other than that, there are no other errors, which even that stopped working for some reason. And martin, I'll test out the var_dump tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($_SESSION['errors']);
```

needs to come after you call the validation function

```
validation(($_POST['username']),($_POST['password']));
```